# Is it possible to develop windows desktop native application on a Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a MacBook Air.

I want to make a simple windows application that has buttons to start/stop server(CouchDB Apache) on a Windows computer. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: The best option is to create a VM with Windows.

Comment: Ok, the last thing I wanted was to use VM. But i guess there's no other way out!
Anyway, thanks for the reply

Comment: I don't think so, first of all, it's connected to the Windows Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem, so you have to create the UI in Windows and do the business-logic coding on your mac. But need a compile connection to windows machine.

I am working with RDP on a server now to develop windows applications.
Maybe create a VM on your Mac.

Or you will need to run a Windows installation with "Boot Camp" and run the Windows version of Visual Studio to create the app.

Answer (score 0):

As i know you can not deploy windows form app on mac. but you can create a .net core console application and send start/stop command to it. it will do the same thing if your app is as easy as you told.
this link helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio. of course you should use [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) IDE to create your .net core console application.